# Is there a way to command-line emulate the "kind of sleep" that Windows 11 enters when one picks "Sleep" from the power menu?

Tags: windows, command-line

I want to make my computer sleep from the command line (DOS, PS, or WSL) in a way so that it wakes up when I click the mouse or press a key - exactly how it works when one clicks "Start -< Power -> Sleep"

The following **DO NOT WORK** - *all* of the below put the machine into some other kind of deeper sleep, which ignores keyboard/mouse input (it's a laptop plugged into a monitor - I have to open its lid and press the power button to wake it, which messes up my desktop...)

```
psshutdown -d -t 0

C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0

C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 1,1,0

[Void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") ; $PowerState = [System.Windows.Forms.PowerState]::Suspend;  [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::SetSuspendState($PowerState, $false, $false);

(aka)

powershell -Command "[Void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms') ; $PowerState = [System.Windows.Forms.PowerState]::Suspend;echo Zzzz;[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::SetSuspendState($PowerState, $false, $false);"
```

Is there maybe some way to inject key-presses into the windows buffer?  This would probably do the trick, if it's possible?:-
Ctrl-Esc, Up-Arrow, Right-Arrow, Right-Arrow, Right-Arrow, Right-Arrow, Enter, Enter

Does the Accessibility subsystem have any easy way to find desktop UI elements (the start menu) and trigger actions on them maybe ?  (A click on the "Sleep").

Obviously - the best answer would be if anyone knows exactly what system call windows itself is making when that sleep button is pressed!

Comment: Calling SetSuspendState  with rundll32 is always incorrect

Comment: I'm investigating "PwrTest" from the windows WDK 8.1 presently... (big download) - I ran a "strings" on explorer.exe (the program which presents those power buttons) which lead me to some imports and exports, which google finds inside "PwrTest"...

Comment: This powershell, ahem, "one-liner" does the trick, extremely inelegantly, (all the sleeps are needed):  `$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell; $explorerpid=Get-Process | Select MainWindowTitle,ProcessName,Id | where{$_.ProcessNAme -eq "explorer"} | Select Id;$wshell.AppActivate($explorerpid);sleep 1; $wshell.SendKeys('^{ESC}');sleep 1;$wshell.SendKeys('{UP}');sleep 1;$wshell.SendKeys('{RIGHT}');sleep 1;$wshell.SendKeys('{RIGHT}');sleep 1;$wshell.SendKeys('{RIGHT}');sleep 1;$wshell.SendKeys('{RIGHT}'); sleep 1;$wshell.SendKeys('{ENTER}');sleep 1;$wshell.SendKeys('{ENTER}');`

Answer (score 1):

I guess this literally answers my question, although it's not ideal (takes a long time, is prone to probably going wrong if keys are pressed in the middle).

```bash
powershell - Command "$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$explorerpid = Get - Process | Select MainWindowTitle, ProcessName, Id | where {
  $_.ProcessNAme - eq 'explorer'
} | foreach {
  $_.Id
};
$wshell.AppActivate($explorerpid);
sleep 1;
$wshell.SendKeys('^{ESC}');
sleep 1;
$wshell.SendKeys('{UP}');
sleep 1;
$wshell.SendKeys('{RIGHT}');
sleep 1;
$wshell.SendKeys('{RIGHT}');
sleep 1;
$wshell.SendKeys('{RIGHT}');
sleep 1;
$wshell.SendKeys('{RIGHT}');
sleep 1;
$wshell.SendKeys('{ENTER}');
sleep 1;
$wshell.SendKeys('{ENTER}');
True
```

The above can be put into a `.bat` file, or made into a shortcut to make it easier to get to as well.

If anyone knows the correct way to invoke whatever underlying call the `explorer.exe`process is using to trigger a sleep directly, do please let us know!

Comment: This works if the machine is awake and logged in.  If it woke up by itself in the middle of the night, this does NOT work.  Even more annoying, when windows *does* wake up in the middle of the night, it mutes the volume, so scripts which "beep" to warn you that your PC woke up unwantedly are stuck in the nightmare state of shouting as loud as they can, but nobody is able to hear them :-(

Answer (score 1):

This is another method which doesn't work for me - might work for others though?
(powershell):-

```
$PowrProf = Add-Type -MemberDefinition "[DllImport(`"PowrProf.dll`", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]`npublic static extern bool SetSuspendState(bool bHibernate, bool bForce, bool bWakeupEventsDisabled);" -Name Kernel32 -Namespace Win32 -PassThru 
$PowrProf::SetSuspendState($False, $True, $False) ;echo bForce is not used
```

From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/powrprof/nf-powrprof-setsuspendstate

p.s. The above also shows you how to call arbitrary windows API functions from the command line.  Note that the weird things with backticks ` in front of them are powershell escapes for newline `n and quotes `"

Here also is yet-another, which simply does nothing whatsoever for me:-

```
$Kernel32 = Add-Type -MemberDefinition "[DllImport(`"kernel32.dll`", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]`npublic static extern bool SetSystemPowerState(bool fSuspend, bool fForce);" -Name Kernel32 -Namespace Win32 -PassThru
$Kernel32::SetSystemPowerState($True, $False)
```

Whatever explorer.exe is doing with their "sleep" button is clearly not using any of the above documented APIs - grrr!!